# Run A Simple Java Program in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an assignment for school where I need to download files from github, edit code, and run and test them. I downloaded the files into a general project folder in eclipse, but can't seem to figure out how to run the java files within eclipse. So far I've been getting by with just using the command line, but it would be much faster and more efficient to do everything within eclipse.

There are multiple java files each with a main class. They are all under the same project and I don't want to have to make individual projects for each. Most of my googling has had the answer "right click -> run as -> java project", but I am using eclipse neon and do not see that option. When I try to set up a run configuration, the project does not show up for the project field and if I manually enter it it says that the project does not exist. Any ideas on how to get this working? Thank you.

Edit- The way that I got the files from github was by clicking "File -> Import -> Projects from Git -> Clone URL -> Master (Next) -> Next -> [image: Next]

Comment: *"right click -> run as -> java project"* is correct, but the class need to have a static main.

Comment: Right click on the class with the `main` method.

Comment: any pictures if included in your question will be helpful

Comment: @shmosel Yep, that's what I meant ;-)

Comment: If you just downloaded a collection of .java files, you may need to create a new project first, before Eclipse can understand that these files actually are a project.  Try here: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+eclipse+new+project+existing+source&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Have you, in fact, *created* a Java project and added your source files to it (in the source folder) preserving packaging? ***How*** did you download the files from github?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to launch a Java program is to run it using a Java Application launch configuration. This launch configuration type uses information derived from the workbench preferences and your program's Java project to launch the program.

In the Package Explorer, select the Java compilation unit or class file with the main method you want to launch.
Press the Run [ The Run button ] button in the workbench toolbar or select Run > Run from the workbench menu bar. Alternatively, select Run As > Java Application in the Package Explorer pop-up menu, or select Run > Run As > Java Application in the workbench menu bar, or select Run As > Java Application in the drop-down menu on the Run tool bar button.
Your program is now launched, and text output is shown in the Console View.

Comment: I said that the "run as -> java application" does not even appear and that I had tried that.

Answer (score 0):

> I downloaded the files into a **general project** folder in eclipse

This is your problem - to launch java classes you want a **java project**

Answer (score 0):

OK. It appears that I may have figured this out and have things the way that I want them. Thanks to @markspace for [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20eclipse%20new%20project%20existing%20source&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) link that describes a similar problem. The simple solution was to create a new java project that had the same name as the github folder that I was downloading from, then change the source from default to the local git folder where the files are located. I could then use the other recommended solutions to right click, then run as java application to run everything within eclipse. Thank you everyone for your help.